# ActionBar is not working

Tags: android

I am trying to enable `ActionBar` in an `Activity`.

Here is my `Manifest file`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.assistant.lab.royale"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LabAssistant"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here's the code :

```
.....
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.abmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
.....
```

I'm following the guide over [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). The `ActionBar` menu should show up now according to the guide but all I'm getting is the old options menu. Why?

**Edit** : menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuReset"
        android:alphabeticShortcut="s"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
        android:showAsAction="withText"
        android:title="@string/menu_reset"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuAbout"
        android:alphabeticShortcut="b"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
        android:showAsAction="withText"
        android:title="@string/menu_about"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include `showAsAction` in your `abmenu.xml` items?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_save"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_save"
      android:title="@string/menu_save"
      // This line //
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

Comment: yes I did. will it prevent from showing actionbar? added menu.xml to question.

Comment: Are you calling anything to hide the `titleBar` in `LabAssistant`? Everything that you've posted is correct expect your `Menu` has a second line of `xmlns:android`, but that doesn't make a difference as far as your problem goes.